# How to define a converter type in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have object that I would convert - the converter would be another object with same keys corresponding with the function that takes a string and returns the appropriate type. How do I set the types properly?

I have tried various utility types like `$ObjMap`, `$ObjMapi`, `$TupleMap`, but I did not move forward with it.

```
type FilterType = {|
  q: ?string,
  page: ?number,
|};

const converter: {[$Keys<FilterType>]: (param: string) => mixed} = {
  q: (param: string) => param ? param : null,
  page: (param: string) => parseInt(param),
}

const filter: FilterType = {
  q: null,
  page: null,
}

const search = {
  page: "1",
  q: "aa",
};

Object.keys(converter).forEach(key => {
  if (!search[key]) {
    return;
  } 
  // $FlowFixMe
  filter[key] = converter[key](search[key]);
});
```

This works fine for me, but I would like to get rid of `mixed` type and the `// $FlowFixMe` comment.

[try it](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgFXNAvFA3gHwCgooBHALigH4BnYFOAOwHMAaYqMAQ2YkqsYBXALYAjVO3wBfANyFCAYwD2jOlGWMAbqmQpKuANoASANIQQNADzwkqDJAB8AXUoAKbii7DKdBiwCUUFgOUMJwAB4QACZSQXgcFFDuXJ7eUL5MzIHBnCle1LmpUJRCCAjsJNy8bh5ePvSZ2SEeNBAAkozAyan+7FLyGmoAZoi6lDa69tjxJIml5RxVfFDzfQMqaq0pCgAWcbiLPMsARACMxxVklMdcXBeEsvIA8qIAVhAKwAB0ANbmNK4NNoULp-F8hkoUABRLi7Vx-EBBEIHEhwIZJACEWxQuwMCKcgRRJCgKAgwEEKEYchI-RIAHo6VAjDAEEoAO7wcIAWQgHBGthQePMTjiQJ0qCFICcrmxuPx-jkUgVQA)

Comment: Does something like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATlAvFA3gHygKCigEcAuKAfgGdgU4A7AcwBpCowBDRici+gVwC2AI1SscAXwDc+fKEixEyFAAUOKKqgxQAJAHlhAKwCyHMAB54SMVHMA1AHwAKOwEoMDqE5p0mHqG4OMkRE+ADGAPb0NOzqmijkVspqGlqYWGxksSgcgv6cOXkU2blQ5AIICKxEnNzkBaXongWaAJL0wE4Ngq6sErKR0cBQmuphABbaGURZAEQcHLPVsXVQswCMS-jSA1ExAGZKqOuJR2jpmfVxqAB0xN4QY+N3vWy1PNnxN+8PT99cEFe0iAA) work? I'm having a hard time getting the last part with `Object.keys` to work so this is a first pass that avoids that problem. If you really want that last part, I can spend more time looking at it.

Comment: Yup it works for me, thanks. But what about with the `Object.keys`, is that possible under flow?